# If there is a constant reference to a particular fire department, is "fire department" capitalized?

Tags: capitalization, proper-nouns

If there is a constant reference to a specific fire department, is "fire department" capitalized?

Comment: What is the context? In the name of a specific fire department, you should capitalize "fire department", as in "San Francisco Fire Department".

Comment: What @Andy said. And no, don't capitalize it simply because it's mentioned many times.

Answer (score 2):

This is a question of style upon which reasonable style guides may differ. One influential style guide that addresses the question in considerable detail is *The Associated Press Stylebook* (2002), which gives relevant examples involving fire departments at each stage of its three part coverage of capitalization for "governmental bodies":

> **governmental bodies** Follow these guidelines:
>
> FULL NAME: Capitalize the full proper names of governmental agencies, departments, and offices: *The U.S. Department of State*, *the Georgia Department of Human Resources*, *the Boston City Council*, ***the Chicago Fire Department***.
>
> WITHOUT JURISDICTION: Retain capitalization in referring to a specific body if the dateline or context makes the name of the nation, state, county, city, etc. unnecessary: *The Department of State* {in a story from Washington}, *the Department of Human Resources* {in a story from Georgia}, *the City Council* {in a story from Boston}, ***the Fire Department*** or ***the city Fire Department*** {in a story from Chicago}.
>
> Lowercase further condensations of the name: ***the department***, *the council*, etc.

However, another influential U.S. guide, *The Chicago Manual of Style*, sixteenth edition (2010) seems to favor a somewhat different approach:

> **Names of Organizations: *Governmental Bodies***
>
> **8.61 *Legislative and deliberative bodies*.** The full names of legislative and deliberative bodies, departments, bureaus, and offices are capitalized cross reference to exceptions omitted]. Adjectives derived from them are usually lowercased, as are many of the generic names for such bodies when used alone (as on subsequent mentions). For generic names used alone but not listed here, opt for lowercase.
>
> [Relevant example:] the Chicago City Council; the city council

Since *AP* style calls for "the Boston City Council" and "the City Council," while *Chicago* style calls for "the Chicago City Council" and "the city Council," it seems reasonable to infer that whereas *AP* specifies "the Chicago Fire Department," "the Fire Department," and "the department," *Chicago* would endorse "the Chicago Fire Department," "the fire department," and "the department."

If you have to follow the style preferences of a particular style manual, you should certainly adhere to its preferred way of handling the shortened name of a city fire department. If you are free to follow whatever style you prefer, you can cite *AP* or *Chicago* as support for using the one you like better. But once you opt for a style, stick with it. Nothing is more distracting to a certain type of reader than a style decision that the author applies sporadically and inconsistently.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, no, "fire department" wouldn't be capitalised unless it's part of the full name of the fire department in question. Then it would be treated as a proper noun and so would be capitalised. But although what I've said is consistent with every style guide I've ever read (and I've read a few), some people do insist on capitalising words they feel are important, and some people don't like the inconsistency of seeing "fire department" capitalised in a name and not elsewhere, so you might well see "fire department" capitalised sometimes.

Comment: When subsequent mentions of a proper noun use a shortened form, they are normally capitalized. For instance, the Department's spokesperson ...